# What are the odds of someone having a child and that child being a girl?

Tags: probability, statistics

My logic was that there's a 50% of someone having a child, and if they have a child a 50% of the child being a girl. So  $ 0.5*0.5 = 0.25 $

However, a friend is saying that is very simplistic to say that "there's a 50% of someone having a child" and I should take into consideration factors of age, gender, country, occupation, etc of the person. He says that under my binary logic of "either the person has a child or not", I could reduce everything to having a 50% of chances (having a car accident tonight or not having it, a meteorite falls to Earth tomorrow or it doesn't, etc)

We are not experts in statistics or probability so we would appreciate knowing the appropriate way to approach this question.

Comment: Yeah the logic for the probability of having a child is wrong. If there are two possible outcomes for an event, each of those outcome is not necessarily equally likely to happen.

Comment: A key factor is that parents often have more than one child, which increases the likelihood of having at least one child that is a girl. It is reasonable to assume each child is independently a boy or girl. So, for example, given a person has 3 children, the probability of that person having at least one girl is $7/8$.  It drops to $3/4$ if that person has just two children, and to $1/2$ if that person has 1.